# Powershell gives back Full DN

Tags: powershell

Simple code trying to pull the names of AD groups that a user belongs to:

`Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties MemberOf`

But what I get back is the full DN of each group, like this:

`CN=APP_DUO_MFA_U,OU=Groups,OU=Accounts,OU=BH-ROOT,DC=bh,DC=contoso,DC=org,`

All I want it to return is "APP_DUO_MFA_U".
What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Unless you want to look up that new DN ADUser object, you will have to parse the CN value.

Comment: Well, the `MemberOf` attribute is an array of DNs, you could split them to get the CN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to extract the `CN` value from a `DN`, an efficient way is to remove the unwanted strings.

```
# Using the -replace operator
(Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf -replace '^CN=(.*?),[A-Z]{2}=.*$','$1'

# Using -split 
(Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf.foreach{
    ($_ -split ',?[A-Z]{2}=')[1]
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

For `-replace`, the goal is to remove the beginning `CN=` (`^CN=`). Then remove everything up until the next comma followed by either a domain component (`DC=`) or an organizational unit (`OU=`), which is matched by lazy match `(.*?)` and `,[A-Z]{2}=`. `.*$` matches the remaining characters until the end of the string. Since we used `()` around the lazy match, we can substitute it later as `$1`, which denotes capture group `1`. In short, remove the entire DN and bring back just the part you want to see.

For `-split`, you will have to loop through each `DN`. The `foreach()` method or `Foreach-Object` will suffice. The code will split the string into the DN parts' values. The `CN` value will always be the second part, i.e. index `1`.

Comment: I didn't know `-split` was *RegEx* compatible. Very cool.

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything wrong, the `memberOf` field does indeed contain a list of DNs!

You can either do a second query against AD to resolve the target group's `Name` value:

```
$groupNames = (Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties memberOf).memberOf |Get-ADGroup |ForEach-Object Name
```

Or, if you just need the `CN` (which might well be the same as the `Name`) value, use the regex-based `-replace` operator to remove the RDN and everything from the first the first non-escaped comma:

```
$groupNames = (Get-ADUser johndoe -Properties memberOf).memberOf -replace '^CN=(.*?)(?<=[^\\]),.*$','$1'
```